# $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z) }{z-a} \, dz = 0$ for $f(z)=\sin \pi/z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic for all $z$ where $0 < |z| < 2$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is in this domain as well. I wish to prove that $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z) }{z-a} \, dz = 0$$ for $f(z)=\sin \pi/z$. We can rewrite the integral as a line integral

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z) }{z-a} \, dz = i \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) }{1-\mathrm{e}^{-it}a} \, dt.$$

To show that this is zero, we can expand the integrand into a power series using geometric series

$$\frac{\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right)}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-it}a} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n \mathrm{e}^{-int}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right).$$

So I want to show that

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n \mathrm{e}^{-int}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) \, dt=0.$$

In order to be able to switch the summation and integration, I need to make sure the summand converges uniformly, right? So I wish to apply Weierstrass' M-test to the summand so that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n \mathrm{e}^{-int}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) \, dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-int}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it}  \right) \, dt.$$ How do I do this?

And to finish the problem, I want $$\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-int}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) \, dt=0.$$ But I don't see how I can prove this.

Can you help?

**EDIT:** Added info on $f$ and $a$.

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: @Potato It's usual  that questions are not fully explained. For example, we don't know anything about the parameter $\large a$.

Comment: My apologies, I've tried adding further information on $f$ and $a$. Hopefully it is sufficient to understand the problem (it really is as much as the book gives).

Comment: Yes, I know the residue theorem. I'm not quite sure how to find the residue of this function; I've tried Laurent series expansion but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @BoSchmidt What did you get for the Laurent series expansion?

Comment: @DepeHb What do you mean? It seems isolated to me. It's holomorphic at every point not equal to $0$.

Comment: My bad, I read the function as $1/sin(\pi/z)$. You're right of course, I'm deleting the previous comment.

Comment: I want to expand $\sin(\pi/z)$ around $z=a$ right? So that the prefactor $(z-a)^{-1}$ gets into the Laurent expansion. This gives $\sin(\pi/a)/(z-a) - \frac{\cos(\pi/a) \pi}{a^2}(z-a) + \cdots$ which is a nonzero residue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last integral can be rewritten as $$\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-int}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) \, dt=
i\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-i(n-1)t}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) \, d{(e^{-it})}.$$
Denoting $w=e^{-it},$ we have
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-i(n-1)t}\sin \left( \pi \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right) \, d{(e^{-it})}=\int\limits_{|w|=1}{w^{n-1}\sin{\pi w}\ dw}=0$$
for $n\geqslant{1}$ since integrand is analytic in the unit disc.
**Note:**   The expansion into geometric series is valid only for $|a|<1.$ For $|a|>1$
$$\dfrac{1}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-it}a}=-\dfrac{1}{a\mathrm{e}^{-it}(1-\tfrac{e^{it}}{a})}=-\dfrac{1}{a\mathrm{e}^{-it}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{e^{it}}{a}\right)^n}.$$

Comment: Nice! How did you get the first equality where you changed the integration over $dt$ to $d(\mathrm{e}^{-it})$? I'm not sure how the $d(\mathrm{e}^{-it})$ integrations work.

Comment: $d(e^{-it})=-ie^{-it}\,dt$

Comment: Ah, so it's shorthand for the time derivative of $\mathrm{e}^{-it}$. Gotcha. Thank you!